# Get max date from subquery - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've query which will return distinct date from column [InsertDate]

```
SELECT DISTINCT [InsertDate] FROM cust
```

Now I want to get max date from the result returned by the query. Here the query, but it didn't work

```
SELECT max(SELECT DISTINCT [InsertDate] FROM cust) from cust
```

Example:
2015-12-01
2016-01-01

Result:
2016-01-01

Comment: `SELECT max([InsertDate]) from cust`

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 [InsertDate] from cust Order by InsertDate desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below query

```
SELECT max(InsertDate)
FROM (select DISTINCT InsertDate FROM cust) k
```

the question is why don't you just simply use below?

```
select max(InsertDate) FROM cust
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I know the second option will work but I wanna to know why the first options doesn't work. Thanks